# Chart.js 2.7.0 Can the font size of an axes change at runtime?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js2

I have the chart filling the height and width of the window.

Upon creation of the chart, the yaxes does get some options like these:

```
ticks: { display: true, min: 0, beginAtZero: true, max: 120, fontSize: 14 }
```

As the window is resized (aka browser), the smaller you shrink the window, the less space that is available for the chart, because of my initial font sizes for the Title, the x-axes, my two y-axes, and the legend (though I didn't set a font there, I'm hoping you can).

In my old fancy charts (VisiFire), "for free", the fontsize of the titles, and axes, shrank (and expanded, of course).  I'd like to do the same here.

How can that be achieved?

Ya know, something like:

```
chart.scales['y-axes-1'].options.ticks.fontSize = new_font_size
```

And if so, where would I put it?

I just tried the animation onProgress event (for currentStep 1), but that's too late I guess (or I shouldn't be setting options.ticks.fontSize, but something else).  I was trying to find an event before animation onComplete, where I could set this.  And I set it, and every step after currentStep 1, I printed out the fontsize, and it was my new fontsize, but it didn't change a thing.

Thank you.

EDIT: Is it that we can't update fontSize of the ticks?  Because I just tried this:

```
chartInstance.scales['Dataset1'].options.ticks.fontSize = 24;
chartInstance.scales['Dataset1'].options.ticks.min = -100;
chartInstance.scales['Dataset1'].options.scaleLabel.labelString = 'foo bar';
chartInstance.scales['Dataset1'].options.scaleLabel.fontSize = 36;
```

And it got updated to a min of -100, the label changed to foo bar, the fontSize of that label jumped to 36, but the sticks stayed the same.  They didn't go to 24.

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/178/

This shows what I mean.  After running the fiddle, within 5 seconds (setInterval) it will perform an update.  And the scale ticks won't update their fontSize.  I'm using this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js, when I use 2.4.0 it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I did discover a bug, confirmed as one here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4896

EDIT: Well, it was marked as a bug!  Now, it looks like either there is a work-around, or they changed things in 2.7.0, and this is now how you set it, or what, but ...

it looks like minor and major are used:

myLiveChart.scales['myAxis'].options.ticks.minor.fontSize = 36